# How to use a lambda as a default argument?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, syntax-error

I'm trying to make a function that will take an optional parameter, `callback`, which must be a function.

I'd like the default value for this function to be nothing - i.e. a function that does nothing. The way that seems to make sense to me is:

```py
do_the_thing()
do_the_thing(callback = print) # or message.respond, or log_to_file, etc

def do_the_thing(**kwargs):
    cb = kwargs.get('callback', lambda x: pass)
    # do things
    cb("Things have been done.")
```

But I get a syntax error at the end of "pass".

What's the correct way to go about this?

Comment: Just use `cb = kwargs.get('callback', lambda _: None)`. This is necessary because `pass` is a statement, not an expression which is what `lambda` requires. You could also use `def do_the_thing(callback=lambda _: None):` and not need to do the `kwargs.get()` (and just use `callback("Things have been done.")`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pythons `lambda` are more restricted than normal `def` functions. Typically `lambda` requires an expression in the body ... but `pass` is just a statement. So the obvious solution would be to use:

```py
lambda x: None  # or since you don't use x "lambda _: None"
```

---

As a rule of thumb: everything that can be assigned to a variable can also be in the body of a `lambda`. You can find out more about the grammar in the [The Python Language Reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda)

```
6.13. Lambdas

lambda_expr        ::=  "lambda" [parameter_list] ":" expression
lambda_expr_nocond ::=  "lambda" [parameter_list] ":" expression_nocond
```

and similar for [`pass`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#simple-statements)

```
7. Simple statements

simple_stmt ::=  expression_stmt
[...]
                 | pass_stmt
[...]

pass_stmt ::=  "pass"
```

---

Or in the more formal [Full Grammar specification](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html#full-grammar-specification). Here you can use any `test` for assignment and lambda bodies, and a `test` can be an `expr`. Here is a (severly) shorted part:

```
pass_stmt: 'pass'

annassign: ':' test ['=' test]
lambdef: 'lambda' [varargslist] ':' test

test: or_test ['if' or_test 'else' test] | lambdef
or_test: and_test ('or' and_test)*
and_test: not_test ('and' not_test)*
not_test: 'not' not_test | comparison
comparison: expr (comp_op expr)*
```